# Como focar o input de um formulário constantemente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um formulário e preciso dar foco em um input novamente até que ele satisfaça o requerido, exemplo:

```js
$('#text1').blur(function() {
  var teste = $('#text1').val().length;
  console.log(teste);
  if(teste > 5){
    $('#text1').focus();
  }else{
    $('#text2').focus();
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
Input 1:
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1">
</label>
<br><br>
<label>
Input 2:
<input type="text" name="text2" id="text2">
</label>
```

É possível proceder desta forma?

Comment: Qual seria o problema?

Comment: Bom dia Paulo, o problema estava com o load da página, pois este formulário advinha de json e como estava usando um js externo com algumas funçoes o mesmo não funcionava de acordo e o focus() como também outras funções do jquery não funcionavam, copiei as funções do js abaixo do formulário e funcionou. vou tentar descobrir o motivo para colocar uma resposta.

Comment: talvez você estava tentando executar o código do focus antes de incluir o jQuery na sua pagina, você deve ter certeza que o jQuery está sendo incluido antes (acima) do que os códigos, senão não vai funcionar mesmo. e eu também sugiro que o código esteja dentro de um `$(document).ready(function(){ });` pois ai garante que só será atribuido evento ao elemento depois que ele ja estiver criado. E se ele for criado com Ajax, você pode executar os códigos no método `.done()` do ajax que executa quando o ajax termina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso você deve usar o [.focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) já que o [.blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) funciona apenas para detectar quando o elemento perde o foco.

```js
$('#text2').focus(function() {
  $('#text1').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
Input 1:
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1">
</label>
<br><br>
<label>
Input 2:
<input type="text" name="text2" id="text2">
</label>
```

Comment: Eu não consigo compreender o porque desta resposta ter sido marcada como correta, afinal ela produz o mesmo resultado que do jeito que está feito a pergunta. Aliás a forma que está na pergunta é bem mais correta, porque sempre que o usuário clicar fora do campo ou clicar em outro campo ou apertar tab, sempre irá voltar a focar o campo em questão, e dessa forma que está nesta resposta você consegue tirar o foco clicando fora do campo.

Comment: Minha resposta foi baseado na pergunta antes dela ser editada, foi dessa forma que compreendi. Ele queria que, mesmo o usuário clicando em outro input, o foco permanecesse em apenas um dele. Com a edição da pergunta, basta ele utilizar .focus e .blur.